# .net - failed to create app domain

Tags: .net, appdomain

just looking for  abit of guidance here if possible.
I recently downloaded a .net component for VS 2008 to handle sftp.
After struggling with it for a day i uninstalled and deleted it.
When going back into VS 2008, any of my previous projects have this error
at the bottom in the error window:

failed to create app domain.

I was going to do a re-install, but is there anything I can try before I resort to this?

thanks again

DD

Comment: Do you get this error upon project/solution load, or everytime you try to debug a project?

Comment: its every time do file --> open --> website

Comment: went for the re-install, fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorted it in the command prompt with caspol -reset